# Component inside component in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make use of Mantine's App shell (https://mantine.dev/core/app-shell/) in React Router to have it enabled on only specific routes.

How is it possible to implement this.

Usually, to display a component I would to the following, for example:

```
<Route element={<SidebarLayout {...{ inactive, setInactive }} />}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
```

But in this case, I got way more code (based on the example in the docs) - I'm planning to add a component inside this `<AppShell>` Component (please look all the way down):

```
<AppShell
      styles={{
        main: {
          background:
            theme.colorScheme === "dark"
              ? theme.colors.dark[8]
              : theme.colors.gray[0],
        },
      }}
      navbarOffsetBreakpoint="sm"
      asideOffsetBreakpoint="sm"
      navbar={
        <Navbar
          p="md"
          hiddenBreakpoint="sm"
          hidden={!opened}
          width={{ sm: 200, lg: 300 }}
        >
          <Text>Application navbar</Text>
        </Navbar>
      }
      aside={
        <MediaQuery smallerThan="sm" styles={{ display: "none" }}>
          <Aside p="md" hiddenBreakpoint="sm" width={{ sm: 200, lg: 300 }}>
            <Text>Application sidebar</Text>
          </Aside>
        </MediaQuery>
      }
      footer={
        <Footer height={60} p="md">
          Application footer
        </Footer>
      }
      header={
        <Header height={70} p="md">
          <div
            style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", height: "100%" }}
          >
            <MediaQuery largerThan="sm" styles={{ display: "none" }}>
              <Burger
                opened={opened}
                onClick={() => setOpened((o) => !o)}
                size="sm"
                color={theme.colors.gray[6]}
                mr="xl"
              />
            </MediaQuery>

            <Text>Application header</Text>
          </div>
        </Header>
      }
    >
      <Text>Resize app to see responsive navbar in action</Text> <-- PLANNING TO ADD COMPONENT HERE BASED ON ROUTE
    </AppShell>
```

How can I integrate this whole thing in React Router?

Comment: Does `Outlet` suit your needs? https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet

Comment: @user4980215 Yes, that's actually what I was looking for. Thank you! Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the "SidebarLayout" name implies, you are asking how to implement what is called a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). Layout routes generally render some common logic and UI elements/components, and an [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) component for nested routes to render their content into. You generally render the `Outlet` component where you'd normally render the `children` prop.

Example:

Render an `Outlet` below the `Text` component.

```
<AppShell
  ...
>
  <Text>Resize app to see responsive navbar in action</Text>
  <Outlet /> // <-- render Outlet here for nested routes
</AppShell>
```

Usage:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<SidebarLayout {...{ inactive, setInactive }} />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
    ... other routes with SidebarLayout ...
  </Route>

  ... other routes w/o SidebarLayout ...
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 ways:

#### Loading AppShell in a wrapper function:

By loading the `AppShell` component inside a `wrapper` function, you can wrap your sub-components by passing them based on the `route` path.

1. You need to create a separate `wrapper` component, let's call it `withAppShell` component, now you can load it as follows:

```
export const withAppShell = (ChildComponent) => 
    ( 
        <AppShell ... // App Shell code start
        <ChildComponent /> // the part where you wish to load your child component
        </AppShell> // App Shell code end
    )
```

2. To use it, first import, then:

```
withAppShell(ChildComponent);
```

#### Loading AppShell in a wrapper component:

Feels similar to the first one, but is not-

1. Create the component:

```
export const AppShellWrapper = ({children}) => 
    (
        <AppShell ... //start
        {children}
        </AppShell> //end
    )
```

2. Using it, first import, then:

```
<AppShellWrapper>
   <ChildComponent />
</AppShellWrapper>
```

Comment: I prefer the second method btw, because you can manage it much easily and can have more than one component inside the wrapper without having to create a separate component for that use-case.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a Higher Order Component with the first example, but it neglects to pass the `props` object through to the `AppShell` and decorated `Component`. It's a regular function so it should be called `withAppShell` instead of `WithAppShell` like a React component. E.G. `const withAppShell = Component => ({ inactive, setInactive, ...props }) => (<AppShell {...{ inactive, setInactive }}><Component {...props} /></AppShell>);`. Neither of these solutions lend themselves to working nicely with a group of nested routes though.